# jQuery templates and selects... "tag" way of producing a select pulldown with an option selected?

Tags: jquery, templates, knockout.js

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way I could write a jQuery template (using template tags only) to create a select pull down with an option selected.
I already have an object with two parameters: the key/value list of options and the selected option. 
To make matters worse: I don't have the index of the selection, I only have the option string.

```
var optionObj = { optionsList: jsonlist, selectedOption: selectedOptionText };
```

I have been using KnockoutJS and it works great, but (as far as I can see) it doesn't suport option selection based upon the option text value.

Any ideas?

I just came up with *this*, but maybe there's a better way?

```
<script id="tmplTextOptions" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each optionsList}}
        <option value="${Key}"
        {{if Value==selected}} selected="selected" {{/if}}
        >${Value}</option>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a selected property to each option in your optionsList and store 'selected="selected"' for the selected one.  Then in each option you can output something like this:

`<option value="${Key}" ${Selected}>${Value}</option>`

Comment: Yeah, that might be a good idea. It would cover multiple selects as well. +1.  The only drawback is that I'm populating the options list via a web service, and it's returning just a Key/Value pair. Would have to make it a model array that contains three elements. Probably not a biggie.